# Checagem de tipos em tempo de compilação ADVPL

Tags: advpl

Estou usando a linguagem ADVPL no meu estágio e tendo muitos problemas com erros de tipo, escopo de variável, etc. Coisas em geral que, ao meu ver, deveriam ser verificadas em tempo de compilação, porém eu só consigo ver o erro em tempo de execução e para tal é necessário logar no sistema, acessar o módulo, etc, etc...

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe alguma forma de fazer a checagem de tipos em tempo de compilação usando ADVPL ou se existe alguma versão mais nova da linguagem que faz isso.

Tentei procurar sobre checagem de tipos em tempo de execução usando ADVPL mas tudo que encontro são artigos relacionados apenas à compiladores e não à linguagem em si.

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93117/discussion-on-question-by-gabriel-belini-checagem-de-tipos-em-tempo-de-compilaca)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gabriel,
   Desconheço alguma forma de testar tipos na hora da compilação em Advpl, os tipos são checados no runtime do programa mesmo! Com o Totvs Developer Studio Baseado no Eclipse tem-se uma analise sintática e semântica melhor!
Se for usar pode verificar qual é o que mais se aqueda a você segue os links:

- Versão 12 http://ds.totvs.com/tds11_2/
- Versão 13 http://ds.totvs.com/tds11_3/

Prefiro a 12 ele e mais leve e syntax hilight e melhor que a do 13, pode usar o VS code também tem o plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KillerAll.advpl-vscode.
Ele o debug e compilação estão funcionando bem com o Protheus V12, na 11 esta dando alguns problemas.

### Testar sem ter que abrir o ERP manualmente

Para testar seu programa sem ter que abrir o ERP manualmente existe essa possibilidade?
Sim ela existe você deve usar o seguinte trecho de código no programa:

```
PREPARE ENVIRONMENT EMPRESA("02") FILIAL("01") MODULO "COM"
RESET ENVIRONMENT
```

Exemplo abaixo usando o trecho de código:

`User Fuction NomeFucao()
 Local variável 
 Local outravar 
 Private varival 
 PREPARE ENVIRONMENT EMPRESA("02") FILIAL("01") MODULO "COM"
   PROCESSAMENTO DO SEU PROGRAMA AQUI 
   ..... 
   ..... 
   ....
 RESET ENVIRONMENT
Return Variável ou Nil`

Após isso você manda executar o smartclient e no programa inicial U_NomeFucao ao invés de SIGAMDI ou SIGAADV. A sim poupa tempo de abrir o ERP, isso se seu programa for somente background e não envolver componentes visuais!

Para testar os tipos Variáveis pode usar as funções

- ClearVarSetGet
- ContType   (Retorna um array com o tipo da variável. Diferente do ValType, retorna o tipo original da variável)
- Type   (Retorna o tipo de dado de uma expressão ou variável)
- VarRef  (Cria referência entre duas variáveis)
- ValType   (Retorna um caractere que identifica o tipo de dado da variável informada através do parâmetro)
- VarSetGet   (Permite associar um bloco de código a uma variável de programa do Advpl, onde o bloco de código será chamado quando a variável for acessada)
- Link da Documentação: http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6063952

Agora que você sabe com testar as variaves ai vamos para os Cast no Advpl e muito livre e tem função converter tudo vou colocar apenas algumas e deixar o link da documentação oficial da TOTVS.

- Val( < cString > )   Converte uma sequência de caracteres que contêm dígitos em um valor numérico.
- CtoD( < cData > )   Converte uma string formatada para o tipo data
- cValToChar( < xParametro > )   Converte uma informação do tipo caractere, data, lógico ou numérico para string, sem adição de espaços na informação.

Assim você pode ver o restante de acordo com sua necessidade na documentação link http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6063599

Esse outro link traz uma lista com todas as funções o SDK documentadas veja de acordo com sua necessidade link http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6063359

### O que fazer com os erros e exceções

Pode usar a biblioteca tryexception

```
#include "tryexception.ch" 
Static Function TrySample2() 
  Local bError := { |oError| MyError( oError ) } 
  Local oError 
  ..
  TRYEXCEPTION USING bError 
   //Forçando um erro para avalia-lo. 
   __EXCEPTION__->ERROR := "__EXCEPTION__" 
  CATCHEXCEPTION USING oError 
     //"Se ocorreu erro, após o BREAK, venho para cá" 
     MsgInfo( oError:Description , "Peguei o Desvio do BREAK" ) 
  ENDEXCEPTION 
  MsgInfo( "Continuo após o tratamento de erro" ) 
Return( NIL )
```

Ela esta no GitHub link https://github.com/NaldoDj/BlackTDN/blob/master/include/tryexception.ch

Desenvolvida pelo Marinaldo do Black TDN http://www.blacktdn.com.br/

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

A linguagem ADVPL possui tipagem dinâmica, ou seja o tipo é definido conforme você o atribui.
o que no caso :

```
valor := 1
valor := "Um"
```

Não seria reportado como um erro em tempo de compilação.

Para ajudar nesse quesito utilizamos um manual de boas prática e nele
contém dicas de convenções e de como organizar o seu código.

http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22480357

Para Desenvolvimento sugerimos a utilização da IDE TOTVS Develop Studio

http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=107939969

Você tbm pode utilizar o Visual Studio Code com essa extensão:

pesquise no github killerall/advpl-vscode

Comment: Caso queira utilizar o vscode o link é:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KillerAll.advpl-vscode

Answer (score 2):

O ADVPL é uma linguagem que tem sua origem no Clipper. Para você iniciar nela você pode utilizar qualquer manual de Clipper como base, porem recomendo fortemente a leitura do material disponível em:

http://tdn.totvs.com/display/framework/SDK+Microsiga+Protheus

Trabalhar com ela é super simples se você tiver conhecimento em programação estruturada.
Sobre a tipagem, o advpl é muito mais parecido com javascript do que com java. Não sendo fortemente tipado. O que facilita muito no desenvolvimento de regras de negocio ( que é o foco dela).

Caso tenha algo mais especifico com o código fonte, abra uma pergunta com o mesmo para que possamos ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Com o lançamento da nova versão do TOTVS Application Server 64 bits, batizado de "Lobo Guará", será possível programar usando um novo código AdvPL, diferenciado pela extensão do arquivo, com pontos fortes na orientação a objetos e tipagem de variávels -- linguagem TL++.

Para maiores informações, acesse o Link da documentação oficial do TL++ no TDN -- http://tdn.totvs.com/display/tec/Tipagem+Forte